# Spring cloud stream kafka binder KTable not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to build and then get KTable by SCSt channels. But it is not working. Input KTable has no data but if i try to look into KSTream aggregation(toStream()) i can see some data.
I see, KTable is not queryable and it has not a queryable name.

Class:

```
@Slf4j
@EnableBinding({LimitBinding.class})
public class CommonWorker {

  @Value("${app.dataflow.out-destination}")
  private String customerOut;

  private LimitCustomersHelper custHelper = new LimitCustomersHelper();

  @StreamListener(CUSTOMER_IN)
  public void groupCustomersByLimitIdKTable(KStream<Key, Envelope> input) {
   input
        .filter(custHelper::afterIsNotNull)
        .groupBy(custHelper::groupBy)
        .aggregate(
            custHelper::create,
            custHelper::aggregate,
            custHelper.materialized(customerOut)
        );
  }

  @StreamListener
  public void checkCustomerasTable(@Input(CUSTOMER_OUT) KTable<StringWrapper,LimitCustomers> customers){
    customers.toStream().peek(StreamUtils::peek);
  }
```

Bindings:

```
public interface LimitBinding {

  String CUSTOMER_IN = "customer-in";
  String CUSTOMER_OUT = "customer-out";


  @Input(CUSTOMER_IN)
  KStream<Key, Envelope> customerInput();

  @Input(CUSTOMER_OUT)
  KTable<StringWrapper, LimitCustomers> customersStream();

}
```

application.yml:

```
server.port: 0
spring:
  application.name: connect-producer
  cloud.stream:
    kafka.streams.binder.configuration:
      schema:
        registry.url: http://192.168.99.100:8081
      default:
        key.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
        value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
    schema.avro.dynamic-schema-generation-enabled: true
    bindings:
      customer-in:
        contentType: application/*+avro
        destination: ${app.dataflow.in-destination}
        group: ${app.dataflow.in-destination}
      customer-out:
        consumer.materializedAs: ${app.dataflow.out-destination}

app.dataflow:
  in-destination: customer_link
  out-destination: customer_link.next


spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder:
  brokers: 192.168.99.100:9092
  configuration.application.server: 192.168.99.100:9092
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding topic name simular table name

Comment: what do you mean by topic name simular table name?